# Compilation error :type mismatch found when validating sign up form passwords in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I try to validate sign up form using Play framework 2.1.1 and scala. I got

**Compilation error :type mismatch; found : (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Int) => models.Contact required: (String, String, String, String, String, (String, String), String, Int) => ?**

**models.scala :**

```
package models

case class Contact(firstname: String, lastname: String, jobtitle: String, phone:String, email: String, password: String, companyname: String, employeescount: Int)
```

**Application.scala :**

```
 val contactForm = Form(
  mapping(      
    "firstname" -> nonEmptyText(minLength=2, maxLength=10),
    "lastname" -> nonEmptyText(minLength=2, maxLength=10),
    "jobtitle" -> nonEmptyText(minLength=2, maxLength=10),
    "phone" -> nonEmptyText(minLength=2, maxLength=10),      
    "email" -> (email verifying nonEmpty),

    "password" -> tuple(
        "main" -> text(minLength = 6),
        "confirm" -> text
    ).verifying(
        // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
        "Passwords don't match", { case (p1, p2) => p1 == p2 }
      ).transform({case (p, _) => p}, {p => p -> p}),

  "companyname" -> nonEmptyText,
    "employeescount" -> number
  )(Contact.apply)(Contact.unapply)
)
```

**index.scala.html**

```
@form(routes.Application.save()) {      
        @text(contactForm("firstname"), '_label -> "First Name : ", 'toto -> "titi")
        @text(contactForm("lastname"), '_label -> "Last Name : ", 'toto -> "titi")
        @text(contactForm("jobtitle"), '_label -> "Job Title : ", 'toto -> "titi")
        @text(contactForm("phone"), '_label -> "Phone : ", 'toto -> "titi")
        @text(contactForm("email"), '_label -> "Email : ")

        @password(contactForm("password.main"), '_label -> "Password : ")
        @password(contactForm("password.confirm"), '_label -> "Confirm Password : ")

        @text(contactForm("companyname"), '_label -> "Company Name : ", 'toto -> "titi")
        @select(
            contactForm("employeescount"), 
            options(
                "0" -> "0-10",
                "1" -> "10-100",
                "2" -> "100-1000",
                "2" -> " > 1000"
            ),
            '_label -> "Employees"
        )

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Contact.password` is a `String`, but in `mapping` `password` field is a `(String, String)`. You can not use tuple instead of `String` parameter in `Contact.apply`.

You should transform your `Mapping[(String, String)]` to `Mapping[String]` like this:

```
"password" -> tuple(
    "main" -> text(minLength = 6),
    "confirm" -> text
).verifying(
  // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
  "Passwords don't match", ps => ps._1 == ps._2
).transform[String]({ps => ps._1}, {p => p -> p})
```

Ugly solution:

```
mapping(
  ...
  "password" -> tuple(
      "main" -> text(minLength = 6),
      "confirm" -> text
  ).verifying(
    // Add an additional constraint: both passwords must match
    "Passwords don't match", ps => ps._1 == ps._2
  )
  ...
){
  (firstname: String, lastname: String, jobtitle: String, phone:String, email: String, passwords: (String, String), companyname: String, employeescount: Int) =>
    Contact(firstname, lastname, jobtitle, phone, email, passwords._1, companyname, employeescount)
}{
  (c: Contact) => Option((c.firstname, c.lastname, c.jobtitle, c.phone, c.email, c.password -> c.password, c.companyname, c.employeescount))
}
```

Comment: After add this verifying and tranform code i got following error.missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was: ?

Comment: @Ram: There should be information about exact position in the source code in error message, could you show it? You could try to specify type for `transform` method like this: `.transform[String](...`

Comment: Great,now the error resolved. But If enter wrong passwords,it does not display error message like "Passwords don't match".

Comment: @Ram: I guess it's a bug in `Mapping`. You could try an ugly solution from my answer.

Comment: I tried the ugly code,but it again shows error at => of binding. type mismatch; found : (String, String, String, String, String, (String, String), String, Int) => models.Contact required: (String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Int) => ?

Comment: @Ram: Note that there is no `transform` in an ugly solution.

Comment: If i remove transform error not occurs.But password not validated.